# nesting promises in vuex, why?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise, vuex

I'm maintaining `vue` code from my former programmer.

I've found this code in his `vuex` module.

```js
import axios from "axios";
import qs from "qs";
import httpi from "../httpInstance";  // this is just a wrapper for axios

const getPromise = (context, url) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    httpi.get(url).then(
      (response) => {
        resolve(response);
      },
      (error) => {
        reject(error);
      }
    );
  });
};

// same repeated for 'put', 'post' etc...
```

I'm wondering why he nested promises this way.

In `ACTIONS`, he uses this wrapper to call back-end API like below.

```js
const actions = {
  [ACT_GET_ALL_RULESOURCE]: function (context) {
    return getPromise(context, `${APIURLPREFIX}/polapi/api/rulesource`);
  },
```

What was he trying to achieve by this?

I'm so confused since axios(`httpi`) itself is already a promise. what is the point here?

****edit**

In Vue Component `methods`'s, he uses this actions like below.

```js
getAllRulesource() {
  this.$store.dispatch(`rules/${ACT_GET_ALL_RULESOURCE}`)
    .then((res) => {
      this.rulesourceList = res.data;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      this.msg = "Cannot GET rulesource";
    })
}
```

Comment: "Why"s are tricky; you'd have to ask your former programmer to really find out why.

Comment: Besides there being no need to create a new promise (as you suspect and I concur), the `context` argument is not used. This reads to me like technical debt: code written to create layers of abstraction that might be needed in the future but turn out not to be. Afterwards the code never gets cleaned up because it's tested and working, and a re-examination of the code would be time consuming and costly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prior developer didn't understand promises well enough. Since it appears that `httpi` returns a promise (the OP code calls `then` on it) the function `getPromise` can and should be rewritten as...

```
const getPromise = (context, url) => {
  return httpi.get(url);
};
```

Or removed altogether.  The would-have-been caller can just say...

```
httpi.get('http...').then(response => {
  console.log(response);
}).catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
})
```

Inside a function declared as `async`, the more modern caller syntax is...

```
try {
  const response = await httpi.get('http...');
  console.log(response);
} catch(error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

Comment: I think you would need a call to `await`, like so: `const response = await httpi.get('http...');`